# What does "Oh snap" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, expressions, synonyms, slang

May I ask, what does "oh snap" mean please?

I heard it from the DIY Art competition, when the competitors were waiting for the judges to announce who's the winner.

Competitor A said: I'm nervous.

Competitor B said : I'm so excited.

Competitor C said : Oh snap!

Does "Oh snap" means "Oh what's the result"? or just "Oh I'm excited"?

I found in [the dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/oh_snap) that this word "often used in response to an insult"
But in this situation, I am a confused about the meaning of it.

Comment: Urban dictionary has it pretty good: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OH%20SNAP

Comment: I wouldn't normally expect to hear / see ***Oh*** before ***snap**!* in the cited context. To me that looks reminiscent of (AmE) ***Oh, shoot**!* and (BrE) ***Oh, sugar**!* (euphemistic alternatives to ***Oh, shit**!*). Note that @BobtheMagicMoose's link doesn't actually give the "etymology" - it's from a children's "matching" playing cards game, competing to be the first to shout "Snap!" when two consecutive cards have the same face value.

Comment: What is it you don't understand in the dictionary definition you link to? "An exclamation of agreement or acknowledgment" seems perfectly apposite, i.e. Competitor C is exclaiming her agreement with what one or both of the other competitors said.

Comment: _Oh, snap!_ is a euphemism for _Oh, shit!_ It's intended to express emotion without offending anyone unintentionally by using a taboo word.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Saying you feel the same as somebody else is not expressing agreement.

Answer (score 4):

In the context given, "Snap" is more likely to mean "Me too"; "I'm the same".

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/snap?locale=en):

> **4** *British mass noun* A card game in which cards from two piles are turned over simultaneously and players call ‘snap’ as quickly as possible when two similar cards are exposed.
>
> > ‘The school is also encouraging parents to introduce their children to cards games such as old maid, snap and bridge.’
>
> **4.1** *as exclamation* Said when similar objects turn up or two similar events take place.

In this case, it is an exclamation transferred from the card game where it signifies a match into a situation where there is just a match — the speaker is also excited.

This is completely different from the American usage where it's an innocuous expletive.